# Change directory structure for operator-sdk (Kubernetes) generated project

Tags: kubernetes, operator-sdk

By default operator-sdk generates folder structure as following

root_folder

```
   |- api
   |- config
   |-   |-  crd
   |-   |-  default
   |-   |-  manager
   |-   |-  ..
   |- controllers
   |- hack
```

some folders have been omitted for brevity.

What I am looking for is how to modify this folder structure and configure operator sdk to honor that folder structure.

So say I want to rename `config` to `cmd`, how to achieve this when using [operator-sdk](https://sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/building-operators/golang/tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

You kind of can't. Some stuff is based on special comments and will mostly work no matter the layout but the further you deviate from the default layout, the more of the scaffolding won't work for you in the future.

That said, you can just do whatever you want and not use OSDK again. The underlying Go libraries (controller-runtime, controller-tools) mostly don't care about layouts and it's your software so you can do whatever.

Comment: Thanks for replying. 
Yes, I understand that it would work and it does in a way. For e.g. When I rename ```config``` to say ```cmd``` and run operator locally, it does work but it generates a ```config/rbac/role.yaml``` even when I have moved rbac folder to cmd

Comment: Most controller-gen output paths can be reconfigured via CLI options. It's probably in your Makefile. I think a few can't be though, IIRC webhook gen was hardcoded or something. No reason it needs to be though, patches welcome upstream to fix things :)